# Why can't I access a protected method from a subclass in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Why can't I access a protected method from a subclass in C#?

Class:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected void Method()
    {

    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class B : A
{

}
```

Console application:

```
B b = new B();

b.Method();
```

Compiler says:
Error   1   'Method()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`protected` does **not** mean that client code can access it through a derived class instance.

It **does** mean that derived class code can use it. For example, *this* would be valid:

```
public class B : A
{
     public void SomeMethod()
     {
          Method();
     }
}
```

If you want your *exact* code sample to work, mark `Method` as `public`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but can you tell me _why_ it behaves this way?

According to MSDN documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

"The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class."

That's very subtle.  Is there any further reading available that goes into more depth than the MSDN documentation?

(Sorry, I pressed Enter and it submitted my comment early.)

Comment: @TheCog Because thats the rule for the `protected` access modifier. For what its worth, its the same in C++. Its just the definition of what that keyword does.

Comment: According to same MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx), under Class and Struct Accessibility: "Derived classes cannot have greater accessibility than their base types. In other words, you cannot have a public class B that derives from an internal class A. If this were allowed, it would have the effect of making A public, because all protected or internal members of A are accessible from the derived class."  This info is what helped me to understand your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: In addition, I believe this would be a good use of a public method (as suggested), or a public virtual method so I can override it in subclasses, if necessary.

Comment: @TheCog The subtlety here is that it matters *where the code is*. Code *in the class definition* have access to `protected` members, but random code outside that is just *using* the class does not. I learned it in school, so I'm afraid I don't know of any online super awesome explanations :(